# Tuple unpacking with n values with for loop?

Tags: python, loops, tuples, iteration, permutation

I am doing permutations and I want to print my result in a specific way.

my code:

```
    from itertools import permutations as p

    n = 3      #This can be change

    permu_lst = [i for i in p(range(1, n+1)]

    for a, b, c in permu_lst:
       print(a, b, c)

    Output: 
    1 2 3
    1 3 2
    2 1 3
    2 3 1
    3 1 2
    3 2 1
```

So my question is how can i automate my for loop to print the results when `n` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize this with defining a function that takes as the argument `n` :

```
from itertools import permutations as p
def print_permutations(n):
    permu_lst = [i for i in p(range(1, n+1))]

    for per in permu_lst:
       print(*per)
```

The * before `per` unpacks the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `iterable unpacking operator(*)`

```
from itertools import permutations as p

n = 4      #This can be change
permu_lst = [i for i in p(range(1, n+1))]

for tup in permu_lst:
    print(*tup)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
1 4 2 3
1 4 3 2
2 1 3 4
2 1 4 3
2 3 1 4
2 3 4 1
2 4 1 3
2 4 3 1
3 1 2 4
3 1 4 2
3 2 1 4
3 2 4 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 1
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1
4 3 1 2
4 3 2 1
​
```

Reference: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/